# Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I checked [my site](https://sites.google.com/site/wheresthezbfairlane/) using the Facebook Debugger it gives the following messages:

> **Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
>
> *Admins And App ID Missing:*
>
> fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
>
> *Like Button Tag Missing:*
>
> og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
>
> *Like Button Tag Missing:*
>
> og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.*

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by including some open graph data in meta tags in my HTML:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/logo.png">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com">
```

Comment: I have all those meta tags, but it still complains about fb:admin and fb:app_id I'm going to have to look at the JavaScript more closely. I wish Facebook wouldn't have changed their buttons.

Comment: is this solved? I have a website with a like button and I alwo have the missing app_id but it's not an app,  it's a facebook page!!